# Workflow Target user Fields are coming through null. I can't find documentation on this anywhere

Tags: workflow, email-template, user, merge-field

I can't find any specific documentation on this anywhere, but surely the following fields should pass through right?

{!Target_User.Manager}
{!Target_User.Name}
{!Target_User.Id}

I have the following template and each one of the fields comes back null in my template - whether I 'Send Test and Verify Merge Fields' or run the actual workflow.

```
Hi {!Target_User.Manager},

{!Target_User.Name} was just frozen within Salesforce and will not be able to login. If this is an error, please reach out to Brett Favre.

Please check the following page to see if {!Target_User.FirstName} has any open records that need to be reassigned:

http://packers.my.salesforce.com/apex/InactiveUserRecordReassignment?id={!Target_User.Id}
```

Note: I tried using {!User.Manager} and {!User.Name} but that brings in fields related to **my** user.

Comment: It is a beta feature. I would recommend creating a case with SFDC Support.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of this does seem inconsistent. My issue was a combination of the manager being blank on some of the records I was testing as well some weirdness with the merge fields themselves.

- Re-copying/pasting values from the merge fields seemed to work
- However perhaps testing with Manager
  populated resolved this and allowed the other merge field not to fail?